# Recompose method not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make my composable recompose according to my requirement, as :

```
  @Composable
    fun recomposeDemo() {
        var countState = 0
        Recompose { recompose ->
            Column  //Error in this line
                {
                Text("CountState is: " + countState)
                Button(onClick = { countState++ }) {
                    Text("Count up")
                }
                Button(onClick = {
                    recompose()
                }) {
                    Text("I want to recompose")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is provided here: [Site having this example](https://www.programmersought.com/article/81665761713/)

But the above code produces the following error:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

Is this because of some version issues? I'm using the latest version of Compose ie. "1.0.0-beta03".
How do I use the "Recompose" composable properly for this version?

This is my app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.voodlee0125"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.25"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-beta03'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        useIR = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
//            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
//            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.11'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.IslamKhSh:CardSlider:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.0'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC2'
    // Lottie dependency
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"

    //Autostart settings open
    implementation 'com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'

    // JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.30"

    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:2.2.2"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-core:1.0.0-beta03"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta03"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question.
You can't use a Composable function on the `onClick` lambda,
but you can just rewrite your code with:

```
var countState = remember {mutableStateOf(0)}

Column()
{
    Text("CountState is: " + countState.value)
    Button(onClick = { countState.value++ }) {
        Text("Count up")
    }
}
```

When you click the button:

- the countState `MutableState` value is changed.
- Because of the `countState`, the `Text` is recomposed.

Comment: is there a way I can manually recompose using 'Recompose' ?

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is not composable. It's a regular function.

> **What about the `onClick` lambda?**
>
> Recompose scopes are only created around composable functions. Event handlers, like Button's onClick, are not composable, they're just regular functions. When the click handler is invoked by the framework, it is done so outside of any recompose scope.

You can read more about it in the [Scoped recomposition in Jetpack Compose — what happens when state changes?](https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78) article.

Follow @Gabriele Mariotti advice on how to modify your code.